# How to get code behind variable value into repeater itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, linq, repeater

I have a variable in my code behind  file in asp.net 
 say 
      string str  = "MY Name";

I want to bind this string to a label that is  inside the  in Repeater.

```
    <asp:Label  ID="lblsubjects" runat="server" Text='<%# What to  write here %>'/>
```

The Repeater is binded using a linq query.

Answer (score 3):

See below sample :

**Code Behind :**

```
protected string myString;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myString = "My Name";

    string[] data = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };

    this.rep.DataSource = data;
    this.rep.DataBind();
}
```

**ASPX :**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="<%#myString %>"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2):

use **OnItemDataBound** to access Label.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Myrp" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="R1_ItemDataBound">
```

code behind :

```
public void R1_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    string str = "MY Name";

    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblsubjects")).Text = str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The property needs to be at least `protected`, then you can access it inline:

```
<asp:Label  ID="lblsubjects" runat="server" Text='<%# MyStr %>' />
```

Codebehind:

```
private string _MyStr = "MY Name";
protected string MyStr
{
    get
    {
        return _MyStr;
    }
    set
    {
        _MyStr = value;
    }
}
```

Note that `%#` is for databinding context only. So there must be somewhere a `DataBind` on the container control of the label. If it wasn't in the `GridView` but on the top level of the page you need `this.DataBind()`.